# Angular2 will not render in my .net core MVC app

Tags: angular, asp.net-core-mvc

My main project has NPM installed outside of the wwwroot directory. All my dependencies for Angular in my npm folder are good and referenced correctly in my package.json file. within wwwRoot I have an app folder with my angular components.

My simple test component for now to ensure I am getting something is this:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
    selector: 'pm-app',
    template: `
        <h1>Hello everyone</h1>
 `}) export class AppComponent { }
```

Outside the wwwwRoot folder I have a Typical folder structure for MVC : I have an Areas Folder followed by another folder for each area. Each of these have their own _ViewImports and _ViewStart files along with a shared _layout file.

In my _layout file in the head section I have:

```
 @* Angular 2 references *@
<script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
<script>
    System.import('app').catch(function (err) { console.error(err); });
</script>
```

and then finally in one of my partials I have:

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
<div>
    <pm-app></pm-app>help
</div>
```

at the point of rendering I expect the  tag to be replaced with the template, but it doesn't. Any help appreciated. I've been going round on this one for days now.

Comment: It should not be replaced, but appended: `<pm-app><h1>Hello everyone</h1></pm-app>` will be your end result

Comment: @PierreDuc Yes, that's not happening

Comment: Do you get any errors in the Console in Chrome? I'm using the same setup and it works fine, but there are plenty of opportunities to make mistakes.

Comment: interesting in chrome the references to systemjs.config.js and following script cannot be found. but they are there. and I let intellisense place the reference

Comment: Not sure... bu can you verify that you allow static files? In Startup.cs there should be a line right under app.UserMvc() that says:  app.UseStaticFiles();

Comment: in Startup I have `app.UseFileServer(new FileServerOptions()
            {
                FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
                Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), @"node_modules")),
                RequestPath = new PathString("/node_modules"),
                EnableDirectoryBrowsing = true
            });

            app.UseStaticFiles();`

Comment: Are your script files in the wwwroot folder? I think you'll need to post more of your code to spot the issue.

Comment: yes. The initial file that it fails to find is the systemjs.config.js file and this sits directly under wwwroot

Comment: Through chrome if I go to sources. It's as if the wwwroot folder is being ignored